# How to solve an iterative integral equation for a function in Mathematica 8.0?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, special-functions, integral-equations

I would like to solve the following iterative integral equation in order to find the functional form of $P_{0}(k)$ numerically and then use it subsequently for the rest of my code:

```
     P0[k_?NumericQ] := (2k^2/Pi)*
           NIntegrate[
            P0[t]*NIntegrate[
              q^2*((BesselJ[0, t*q] - (2*BesselJ[1, t*q])/(t*q))*BesselJ[0, k*q] + ((6*BesselJ[1, t*q])/(t*q) - 2*BesselJ[0, t*q])*BesselJ[1, k*q]/(k*q))
              ,{q, 0, Infinity}]
           ,{t, 0, Infinity}];
```

I am assuming that we cannot do it analytically but at least I would like to use the result for the rest of my code.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a solution but may provide a good first step.  The inner integral (a Green's function, I presume) can be performed symbolically.

```
g = Simplify[Integrate[q^2*((BesselJ[0, t*q] - (2*BesselJ[1, t*q])/(t*q))*
    BesselJ[0, k*q] + ((6*BesselJ[1, t*q])/(t*q) - 2*BesselJ[0, t*q])*
    BesselJ[1, k*q]/(k*q)), {q, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> k > 0 && t > 0]]
(* Piecewise[{{(-4*(2*k^4 - 3*k^2*t^2 + 2*t^4)*EllipticE[k^2/t^2] + 
   2*(3*k^4 - 7*k^2*t^2 + 4*t^4)*EllipticK[k^2/t^2])/(Pi*t*(k^3 - k*t^2)^2), 
   k^2 < t^2}, {(-4*(2*k^4 - 3*k^2*t^2 + 2*t^4)*EllipticE[t^2/k^2] + 
   2*(4*k^4 - 7*k^2*t^2 + 3*t^4)*EllipticK[t^2/k^2])/
   (k*Pi*t^2*(k^2 - t^2)^2), k^2 > t^2}}, 0] *)
```

after which the integral equation in the Question becomes,

```
P0[k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(2 k^2/Pi) g P0[t], {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica does not solve integral equations.  So, P0[k] should be expanded as a sum of basis functions, preferably orthogonal. After some manipulation, the integral equation reduces to a matrix equation, which can be inverted. The trick is to select a good set of basis functions, and that depends on having some idea of the form of P0[k]. In the absence of such information, Bessel Functions may be a good start.

Comment: I am willing to learn how to do it with any programming language if that proves to be the only one.